# Visual Studio Code - how to run a file with ansible-playbook arguements?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

I have the ansible extension installed for VS Code.  I can right click on a playbook and run it, but by default the command that is executed is of the format:

```
ansible-playbook myplabook.yml
```

However, i would like to be able to run by passing some ansible-playbook arguements, such as specifying an inventory file and passing in additional args.  It can't seem to figure out from the UI how to do that.

Comment: Did you try setting `ansible.customOptions` in the extension configuration ? => https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscoss.vscode-ansible#user-content-configuration

Comment: yes, that is what i came to fine eventually...

Answer (score 0):

I mean you searched that:

```yaml
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml myplabook.yml
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).